# Converting JSON files to .csv

Tags: json, csv

I've found some data that someone is downloading into a JSON file (I think! - I'm a newb!). The file contains data on nearly 600 football players.

[Here you can find the file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llimllib/fantasypl_stats/8ba3e796fc3e73c43921da44d4344c08ce1d7031/data/players.1440000356.json)

In the past, I have downloaded the json file and then used this code:

```
import csv
import json

json_data = open("file.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

f = csv.writer(open("fix_hists.csv","wb+"))

arr = []

for i in data:
    fh = data[i]["fixture_history"]
    array = fh["all"]
    for j in array:

        try:
            j.insert(0,str(data[i]["first_name"]))
        except:
            j.insert(0,'error')

        try:
            j.insert(1,data[i]["web_name"])
        except:
            j.insert(1,'error')

        try:
            f.writerow(j)
        except:
            f.writerow(['error','error'])

json_data.close()
```

Sadly, when I do this now in command prompt, i get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"fix_hist.py", line 12 (module)
  fh = data[i]["fixture_history"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Can this be fixed or is there another way I can grab some of the data and convert it to .csv? Specifically the 'Fixture History'? and then 'First'Name', 'type_name' etc.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert from json to csv using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/convert-from-json-to-csv-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool: http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

You will need to configure a few things, but should be easy enough.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work...

I also tried using ipython to generate json file and then some python code to generate the .csv but haven't figured that out yet!

Comment: if you can code in php it's as simple as $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('json_url')); and then looping over the data and printing out what you need with csv delimiter

Comment: Not able to do that currently but I follow tutorials. I've amended the question above with some more detail