# How to flatten a JSON array with python

Tags: python, json, list, recursion, json-normalize

I'm dealing with a JSON structure, which is output as follows:

```
{
    "time": "2015-10-20T20:15:00.847Z",
    "name": "meta.response.ean",
    "level": "info",
    "data1": {
        "HotelListResponse": {
            "customerSessionId": "0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A",
            "numberOfRoomsRequested": 1,
            "moreResultsAvailable": true,
            "cacheKey": "-705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58",
            "cacheLocation": "10.178.144.36:7300",
            "HotelList": {
                "@size": 2,
                "@activePropertyCount": 2,
                "HotelSummary": [{
                        "hotelId": 132684,
                        "city": "Seattle",
                        "highRate": 159.0,
                        "lowRate": 159.0,
                        "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "RoomRateDetailsList": {
                            "RoomRateDetails": {
                                "roomTypeCode": 10351,
                                "rateCode": 10351,
                                "roomDescription": "Standard Room, 1 Queen Bed",
                                "RateInfos": {
                                    "RateInfo": {
                                        "@promo": false,
                                        "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                                            "@averageBaseRate": 159.0,
                                            "@averageRate": 159.0,
                                            "@currencyCode": "USD",
                                            "@nightlyRateTotal": 159.0,
                                            "@surchargeTotal": 26.81,
                                            "@total": 185.81
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "hotelId": 263664,
                        "city": "Las Vegas",
                        "highRate": 135.0,
                        "lowRate": 94.5,
                        "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
                        "RoomRateDetailsList": {
                            "RoomRateDetails": {
                                "roomTypeCode": 373685,
                                "rateCode": 1238953,
                                "roomDescription": "Standard Room, 1 King Bed",
                                "RateInfos": {
                                    "RateInfo": {
                                        "@promo": true,
                                        "ChargeableRateInfo": {
                                            "@averageBaseRate": 135.0,
                                            "@averageRate": 94.5,
                                            "@currencyCode": "USD",
                                            "@nightlyRateTotal": 94.5,
                                            "@surchargeTotal": 9.45,
                                            "@total": 103.95
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "X-Request-Id": "dca47992-b6cc-4b87-956c-90523c0bf3bb",
        "host": "getaways-search-app2",
        "thread": "http-nio-80-exec-12"
    }
}
```

As you can see, these are nested arrays. There is much discussion about flattening these recursively. I am unable to flatten the arrays under `HotelSummary`. Any ideas?

- I want to flatten parts of the JSON into the following form:

```
{  
   "customerSessionId":"0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A",
   "numberOfRoomsRequested":1,
   "moreResultsAvailable":"true",
   "cacheKey":"-705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58",
   "cacheLocation":"10.178.144.36:7300",
   "size":2,
   "activePropertyCount":2,
   "hotelId":132684,
   "city":"Seattle",
   "highRate":159.0,
   "lowRate":159.0,
   "rateCurrencyCode":"USD",
   "roomTypeCode":10351,
   "rateCode":10351,
   "roomDescription":"Standard Room, 1 Queen Bed",
   "promo":"false",
   "averageBaseRate":159.0,
   "averageRate":159.0,
   "currencyCode":"USD",
   "nightlyRateTotal":159.0,
   "surchargeTotal":26.81,
   "total":185.81
}


{  
   "customerSessionId":"0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A",
   "numberOfRoomsRequested":1,
   "moreResultsAvailable":"true",
   "cacheKey":"-705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58",
   "cacheLocation":"10.178.144.36:7300",
   "size":2,
   "activePropertyCount":2,
   "hotelId":263664,
   "city":"Las Vegas",
   "highRate":135.0,
   "lowRate":94.5,
   "rateCurrencyCode":"USD",
   "roomTypeCode":373685,
   "rateCode":1238953,
   "roomDescription":"Standard Room, 1 King Bed",
   "promo":"true",
   "averageBaseRate":135.0,
   "averageRate":94.5,
   "currencyCode":"USD",
   "nightlyRateTotal":94.5,
   "surchargeTotal":9.45,
   "total":103.95
}
```

- I have tried using `flattenDict` class. I am not getting the output in the desired format.

```py
def flattenDict(d, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = {}
    for key in d:
        value = d[key]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            value1 = {}
            for keyIn in value:
                value1[".".join([key,keyIn])]=value[keyIn]
            flattenDict(value1, result)
        elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):   
            for indexB, element in enumerate(value):
                if isinstance(element, dict):
                    value1 = {}
                    index = 0
                    for keyIn in element:
                        newkey = ".".join([key,keyIn])        
                        value1[".".join([key,keyIn])]=value[indexB][keyIn]
                        index += 1
                    for keyA in value1:
                        flattenDict(value1, result)   
        else:
            result[key]=value
    return result
```

Answer (score 4):

### Use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) & [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

- `record_path` is the parameter for the main `key` to flatten
- `meta` is the parameter for additional `keys` to flatten, and is for unpacking heavily nested `json` objects.
- `json_normalize` creates column names that include all `keys` to the desired `key`, hence the long column names (e.g. `RoomRateDetailsList.RoomRateDetails.roomTypeCode`)

  - Long column names need to be renamed to shorter versions
  - A `dict` comprehension is used to create a `rename` `dict`.
- The following code takes advantage of the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library

  - `.open` is a method of `pathlib`
  - Works with non-Windows paths too
- For more related questions, see the [json-normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json-normalize) tag. Alternatively, see [How to flatten a nested JSON recursively, with flatten_json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58442723/7758804).

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
from pathlib import Path


# path to file
p = Path(r'c:\some_path_to_file\test.json')

# read json file
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# create dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(data,
                    record_path=['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'HotelList', 'HotelSummary'],
                    meta=[['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'customerSessionId'],
                          ['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'numberOfRoomsRequested'],
                          ['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'moreResultsAvailable'],
                          ['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'cacheKey'],
                          ['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'cacheLocation'],
                          ['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'HotelList', '@size'],
                          ['data1', 'HotelListResponse', 'HotelList', '@activePropertyCount']])

# rename columns:
rename = {value: value.split('.')[-1].replace('@', '') for value in df.columns}
df.rename(columns=rename, inplace=True)

# dataframe view
 hotelId       city  highRate  lowRate rateCurrencyCode  roomTypeCode  rateCode             roomDescription  promo  averageBaseRate  averageRate currencyCode  nightlyRateTotal  surchargeTotal   total                     customerSessionId numberOfRoomsRequested moreResultsAvailable                     cacheKey       cacheLocation size activePropertyCount
  132684    Seattle     159.0    159.0              USD         10351     10351  Standard Room, 1 Queen Bed  False            159.0        159.0          USD             159.0           26.81  185.81  0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A                      1                 True  -705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58  10.178.144.36:7300    2                   2
  263664  Las Vegas     135.0     94.5              USD        373685   1238953   Standard Room, 1 King Bed   True            135.0         94.5          USD              94.5            9.45  103.95  0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A                      1                 True  -705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58  10.178.144.36:7300    2                   2

# save to JSON
df.to_json('out.json', orient='records')
```

### Final JSON Output:

```json
[{
        "hotelId": 132684,
        "city": "Seattle",
        "highRate": 159.0,
        "lowRate": 159.0,
        "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
        "roomTypeCode": 10351,
        "rateCode": 10351,
        "roomDescription": "Standard Room, 1 Queen Bed",
        "promo": false,
        "averageBaseRate": 159.0,
        "averageRate": 159.0,
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "nightlyRateTotal": 159.0,
        "surchargeTotal": 26.81,
        "total": 185.81,
        "customerSessionId": "0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A",
        "numberOfRoomsRequested": 1,
        "moreResultsAvailable": true,
        "cacheKey": "-705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58",
        "cacheLocation": "10.178.144.36:7300",
        "size": 2,
        "activePropertyCount": 2
    }, {
        "hotelId": 263664,
        "city": "Las Vegas",
        "highRate": 135.0,
        "lowRate": 94.5,
        "rateCurrencyCode": "USD",
        "roomTypeCode": 373685,
        "rateCode": 1238953,
        "roomDescription": "Standard Room, 1 King Bed",
        "promo": true,
        "averageBaseRate": 135.0,
        "averageRate": 94.5,
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "nightlyRateTotal": 94.5,
        "surchargeTotal": 9.45,
        "total": 103.95,
        "customerSessionId": "0AB29024-F6D4-3915-0862-DB3FD1904C5A",
        "numberOfRoomsRequested": 1,
        "moreResultsAvailable": true,
        "cacheKey": "-705f6d43:15086db3fd1:-4c58",
        "cacheLocation": "10.178.144.36:7300",
        "size": 2,
        "activePropertyCount": 2
    }
]
```