# Can anyone please suggest how to get the excel output for JSON data that I generated from url from POST call?

Tags: java, report

I have the JSON data that i have got from making a post call to a url, I printed out the JSON data in the console but I need to read that JSON data and get the excel output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Excel, I assume you meant CSV format. It is a format viewable on Excel.

1. to do it manually: http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm
2. to do it programmatically: [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/convert-from-json-to-csv-using-python)
3. In java, the following code is to write to CSV. To write JSON object, you will need to extract which part of the JSON object you want to write because JSON has objects like maps which cannot be simply written into table format. Let me know if it is not clear.

)

```
private static void generateCsvFile(String sFileName) {
try
  {
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName);

  // Start a row
  writer.append("Column1");
  writer.append(',');
  writer.append("Column2");
  writer.append('\n');
  // Start a new row
  writer.append("Row2Column1");
  writer.append(',');
  writer.append("Row2Column2");
  writer.append('\n');

  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Use it:

```
generateCsvFile("/path/sample.csv");
```

Comment: yes, it is excel format. And In order to do it programmatically, I am using java. Can you suggest me sample java based code to convert JSON data into csv/excel?

Comment: Can you respond to the answer?