# Save Json data to csv file

Tags: python

```
r3 = requests.get('www.website.com/api', params=headers)

struct = r3.json()

for k,v in struct.items():
    print (str(k) + str(v))
```

output :

```
FoundCategories[]
PageSize1
Page1
List[{'ExteriorColour': None, 'CategoryPath': '/Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Bentley', 'Subtitle': 'sdf', 'BestContactTime': None, 'StartPrice': 100.0, 'Doors': 0, 'Fuel': None, 'BodyStyle': 'Coupe', 'WofExpires': '/Date(0)/', 'NumberPlate': None, 'ImportHistory': None, 'Transmission': 'Manual', 'EngineSize': 0, 'ListingLength': None, 'StereoDescription': None, 'Category': '0001-0268-7081-', 'Title': 'Bentley Continental 1999', 'Owners': 0, 'IsDealer': False, 'Cylinders': 0, 'AsAt': '/Date(1457728757951)/', 'Odometer': 2000, 'Vin': None, 'Year': 1999, 'StartDate': '/Date(1457326119847)/', 'Region': 'Manawatu', 'Model': 'Continental', 'PriceDisplay': '$100.00', 'Suburb': 'Palmerston North', 'EndDate': '/Date(1457930919847)/', 'RegistrationExpires': '/Date(0)/', 'NoteDate': '/Date(0)/', 'ListingId': 4550689, 'Make': 'Bentley'}]
TotalCount1
```

How do i extract the say, odometer reading from the entry and add it to a csv file

Expected output screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

struct = r3.json()

print(struct)

```
{'TotalCount': 1, 'PageSize': 1, 'FoundCategories': [], 'Page': 1, 'List': [{'AsAt': '/Date(1457733660023)/', 'Model': 'Continental', 'Suburb': 'Palmerston North', 'NoteDate': '/Date(0)/', 'PriceDisplay': '$100.00', 'EndDate': '/Date(1457930919847)/', 'RegistrationExpires': '/Date(0)/', 'StartPrice': 100.0, 'Owners': 0, 'ListingLength': None, 'CategoryPath': '/Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Bentley', 'ListingId': 4550689, 'Subtitle': 'sdf', 'Category': '0001-0268-7081-', 'StartDate': '/Date(1457326119847)/', 'Year': 1999, 'WofExpires': '/Date(0)/', 'ExteriorColour': None, 'Vin': None, 'EngineSize': 0, 'Doors': 0, 'BodyStyle': 'Coupe', 'Title': 'Bentley Continental 1999', 'IsDealer': False, 'Make': 'Bentley', 'Transmission': 'Manual', 'Fuel': None, 'ImportHistory': None, 'Odometer': 2000, 'StereoDescription': None, 'Region': 'Manawatu', 'BestContactTime': None, 'Cylinders': 0, 'NumberPlate': None}]}
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output please?

Comment: @idjaw added screenshot

Comment: Are you looking to only have those headers? Or are you looking to make everything from your json in there where the keys are the headers with their corresponding value?

Comment: @idjaw oh it'll have all of them, sorry, was just showing a small extract of what i need

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv-with-python). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @idjaw   f.writerow(["ExteriorColour", "BestContactTime", "StartPrice", "Doors", "Fuel"])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave the data sanitization to you, however, this overall approach should help you with what you are trying to achieve.

The first thing, you seem to only want what is in the `List` key. So in your data structure that you are receiving, simply get the data inside the `List` key:

```
car_data = struct.get('List')
```

Now that you have your data from `List`, and assuming that every dictionary entry in that list has the same 'keys', simply do a `car_data[0].keys()`, for your fieldnames.

```
fieldnames=car_data[0].keys()
```

Then, simply set up your `DictWriter` with those fieldnames and below is pretty self explanatory:

```
struct = {'TotalCount': 1, 'PageSize': 1, 'FoundCategories': [], 'Page': 1, 'List': [{'AsAt': '/Date(1457733660023)/', 'Model': 'Continental', 'Suburb': 'Palmerston North', 'NoteDate': '/Date(0)/', 'PriceDisplay': '$100.00', 'EndDate': '/Date(1457930919847)/', 'RegistrationExpires': '/Date(0)/', 'StartPrice': 100.0, 'Owners': 0, 'ListingLength': None, 'CategoryPath': '/Trade-Me-Motors/Cars/Bentley', 'ListingId': 4550689, 'Subtitle': 'sdf', 'Category': '0001-0268-7081-', 'StartDate': '/Date(1457326119847)/', 'Year': 1999, 'WofExpires': '/Date(0)/', 'ExteriorColour': None, 'Vin': None, 'EngineSize': 0, 'Doors': 0, 'BodyStyle': 'Coupe', 'Title': 'Bentley Continental 1999', 'IsDealer': False, 'Make': 'Bentley', 'Transmission': 'Manual', 'Fuel': None, 'ImportHistory': None, 'Odometer': 2000, 'StereoDescription': None, 'Region': 'Manawatu', 'BestContactTime': None, 'Cylinders': 0, 'NumberPlate': None}]}



car_info = struct.get('List')
with open('car_info.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=car_info[0].keys())

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in car_info:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hey, i get this error when i try that: writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=struct[0].keys())
KeyError: 0

Comment: @musss I assumed your data structure was `[{}]`. If it is simply a dictionary can you try: `struct.keys()`. Does that work?

Comment: x = struct.keys() gives me dict_keys(['PageSize', 'TotalCount', 'Page', 'FoundCategories', 'List'])

Comment: OK. I know what is going on. You only want what is in the `List` key. Let me update my answer

Comment: @musss Ok. I updated my answer. Can you confirm that you only want the data from `List` or are you looking for all the data in the entire structure including what is in `List`.

Comment: I get : AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: OK. At this point you need to update your question what what your data looks like at this line `struct = r3.json()`. Give the output of `struct` please. The full output.

Comment: @musss please put this in your original question. And delete from these comments.

Comment: posted up in original

Comment: Ok. Great. Now Can you confirm what exactly you want to put in excel? Is it that entire structure, or only the value of 'List':? From your original question it seems like you only want that part.

Comment: I need what's in list. i.e the info about the listing

Comment: OK. @musss This has to work now that I have the right data structure. I tested this code and it works. Answer updated