# JSON like data to CSV file in python - not showing headers correctly

Tags: python, json, csv

I am transforming JSON like data to CSV and having a few issues.

The code is here:

```
import json
import csv

def parse_file(inputed_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as inputed_file:
        content = inputed_file.readlines()
        split_file = open('test.csv', 'w')

        for line in content:
            lines = line.split('\t')

            data = json.loads(lines[0])
            writer = csv.DictWriter(split_file, fieldnames = ["title", "firstname"], delimiter = ',')
            writer.writeheader()
```

The problem is this is adding a header on each row for the data, I want to only have the header displayed once. Then add this for the data to go below the headers:

```
writer.writerow(data)
```

I have looked at this and tried it but failed: [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `DictWriter` outside the loop, and just call `writer.writeheader()` there. Then call `writer.writerow()` inside the loop.

```
def parse_file(inputed_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as inputed_file:
        content = inputed_file.readlines()
        split_file = open('test.csv', 'w')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(split_file, fieldnames = ["title", "firstname"], delimiter = ',')
        writer.writeheader()

        for line in content:
            lines = line.split('\t')
            data = json.loads(lines[0])
            writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: thanks but this still isn't adding the data below the headers :( Please help

Comment: I've changed to a simpler answer

Comment: Thank you so much,  this works,  the only thing is it's putting an empty line between each row.  Do you know how I can change this?

Comment: I don't think it does that automatically. Maybe your JSON data has newlines in it?