# Multi column csv from json in python

Tags: python, json, csv

how to convert json to csv in python. want it open in excel with the lat and long columns.

```
[
  {
    "Lat": "-122.37391463199998",
    "Long": "47.630880207000075"
  },
  {
    "Lat": "-122.38447021399998",
    "Long": "47.70118823100006"
  },
  {
    "Lat": "-122.34729431799997",
    "Long": "47.64717111900006"
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `json` module to convert your string into a dictionary. Then use the `csv` module to save them into a file.

```
import json, csv
json_string = '[{"Lat": "-122.37391463199998", "Long": "47.630880207000075"}, {"Lat": "-122.38447021399998", "Long": "47.70118823100006"}, {"Lat": "-122.34729431799997", "Long": "47.64717111900006"} ]'
data = json.loads(json_string)

with open('foo.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['Lat', 'Long'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Why would you quote with a pipe?

Comment: @AlexHall sorry, I just copy/pasted an example of DictWriter. My bad...

Answer (score -1):

The `csv` module has a handy `writerows()` method on the `DictWriter` class:

```
import csv
import json

data = json.loads(""" My Json """)

with open('lat_long.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Lat', 'Long']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```