# How do I convert JSON data from a URL to CSV in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

In Python, how do I extract particular columns from the following JSON style from a URL then convert them to a CSV file

```
[  
  {  
  "col_1":123,
  "col_2":"value",
  "col_3":"value",
  },
  {  
  "col_1":123,
  "col_2":"value",
  "col_3":"value",
  },
  {  
  "col_1":123,
  "col_2":"value",
  "col_3":"value",
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: If you want to convert json to CSV maybe this answer will be helpfull:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv

Comment: Here an answer to the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv

Comment: Thanks! But this is not from a URL?

Comment: Get your data into a Python `list` of `dict`s, then look at [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)