# Converting json like data to csv

Tags: json, csv, python-2.x

data file looks like the below.
Note that the tags and values are not necesirly fixed (i.e. one file may have 10, next 30, 31 etc)

```
{
        1=6487490
        2=905629
        3=14959 
        4=85
        7=1
        8=
        9=
        16=1
        20=1252903800
        21=557
        22=13
}
```

i want output like this using python2

```
1, 2, 3,4,5,8,9,16,20,21,22
6487490,905629,14959,85,1,,,1,1252903800,557,13
```

where all the tags and values are converted to the csv structure.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv

Comment: Thanks Sergui:  i am getting this error when i try that option.
File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 9 (char 10)

i.e. 
        1=6487490
something is not as expected, when i use 

import json 
with open("small_ds.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)