# Converting Shopify API JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, shopify

Hoping that I may be able to get some assistance in regards to my code. I have spent the last couple of days crawling the site to try and find a response that would fit the requirements and while I found some excellent information, I am still struggling to implement a working version.

I have taken my code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv).

As the title suggests I am trying to take a nested JSON file received from a Shopify Webhook, flatten it and convert it to a CSV.

This is my JSON file:

```
{"id":788032119674292922,"title":"Example T-Shirt","body_html":null,"vendor":"Acme","product_type":"Shirts","created_at":null,"handle":"example-t-shirt","updated_at":null,"published_at":"2018-01-23T03:11:38-05:00","template_suffix":null,"published_scope":"global","tags":"mens t-shirt example","variants":[{"id":642667041472713922,"product_id":788032119674292922,"title":"","price":"19.99","sku":"example-shirt-s","position":0,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"24.99","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":null,"option1":"Small","option2":null,"option3":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"taxable":true,"barcode":null,"grams":200,"image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":75,"weight":200.0,"weight_unit":"g","inventory_item_id":null,"old_inventory_quantity":75,"requires_shipping":true},{"id":757650484644203962,"product_id":788032119674292922,"title":"","price":"19.99","sku":"example-shirt-m","position":0,"inventory_policy":"deny","compare_at_price":"24.99","fulfillment_service":"manual","inventory_management":"shopify","option1":"Medium","option2":null,"option3":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"taxable":true,"barcode":null,"grams":200,"image_id":null,"inventory_quantity":50,"weight":200.0,"weight_unit":"g","inventory_item_id":null,"old_inventory_quantity":50,"requires_shipping":true}],"options":[{"id":527050010214937811,"product_id":null,"name":"Title","position":1,"values":["Small","Medium"]}],"images":[{"id":539438707724640965,"product_id":788032119674292922,"position":0,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"width":323,"height":434,"src":"\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/assets\/shopify_shirt-39bb555874ecaeed0a1170417d58bbcf792f7ceb56acfe758384f788710ba635.png","variant_ids":[]}],"image":null}
```

This is my code:

```
    import csv
    import json

    with open('product.json') as file:
         x = json.load(file)
        print x

    f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))

    f.writerow(["id", "title", "option1", "grams"])

    for x in x:
        f.writerow([x["id"],
                    x["title"],
                    x["variants"]["option1"],
                    x["variants"]["grams"]])
```

When running this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser5.py", line 17, in <module>
    f.writerow([x["id"],
 TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I believe that the issue is to do with the fact that there is not an index reference '[0]', though I am unsure how to assign the key correctly and have failed in all of my attempts to do so.

I am fairly new to Python, I have tried to read as many posts on the site to try not to duplicate the question - apologies if this was in vain.

The desired output that I am looking for from the file would be something like this:

```
id,title,option1,grams
788032119674292922,Example T-Shirt, Small, 200
null,null,Medium,200
```

Any help or guidance that you may be able to offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tim Silver, firstly you need to correct your JSON format. null is not a keyword in python and also some values not properly defined.

Answer (score 2):

your json file contains a single dict(after json.load),
making this line `for x in x:` unnecessary, unless your file contains many lines like the one you provided

the other issue you have is the way you access `x["variants"]["option1"]`
 because `x["variants"]` returns a list of dicts! so your foreach should be there:

```
for item in x["variants"]:
    item["option1"]
    #etc...
```

Comment: @Nullman - Thank you for the recommendation. I have done what you suggested and it has worked on the fields within 'variants', though I cannot pass through the data from the top line in my file. Is there a way to combine this to get the data from the nested and top level data on the same row?

Comment: I figured it out - thanks for the guidance. This is the code that I am now using to write that is working perfectly as intended - have added as a solution. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Given the advice - this is the code that has worked for me on this problem:

```
import csv
import json

with open('product.json') as file:
x = json.load(file)
print x

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb+"))

f.writerow(["url", "sku", "parent_id", "title", "vendor", "product type", 
"tags", "body_html", "image"])

f.writerow([x["handle"], x["id"],
    "",
    x["title"],
    x["vendor"],
    x["product_type"],
    x["tags"],
    x["body_html"],
    x["image"]])

for item in x["variants"]:
    f.writerow(["",item["sku"], x["id"],x["title"],"","","","",
    item["option1"]])
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be easier to parse the JSON first and then use the csv writer as follows (please note I just googled this since I was doing something similar and this solution worked for me). I am pasting the example from the site I found, link to source bellow :)

```
import json
import csv
employee_parsed = json.loads(employee_data)
emp_data = employee_parsed['employee_details']
# open a file for writing
employ_data = open('/tmp/EmployData.csv', 'w')
# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(employ_data)
count = 0
for emp in emp_data:
      if count == 0:
             header = emp.keys()
             csvwriter.writerow(header)
             count += 1
      csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
employ_data.close()
```

*Source:* http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-parse-and-convert-json-to-csv-using-python/