# How to convert this Json into CSV using python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

Trying to convert this large json into csv.Here is the sample JSON

```
    [
    [{
            "User": "Phoebe",
            "text": "Oh my God, hes lost it. Hes totally lost it.",
            "sent": "non-neutral"
        },
        {
            "user": "Monica",
            "text": "What?",
            "sent": "surprise"
        }

    ],
    [{
            "user": "Joey",
            "text": "Hey Estelle, listen",
            "sent": "neutral"
        },
        {
            "user": "Estelle",
            "text": "Well! Well! Well! Joey Tribbiani! So you came back huh? They",
            "sent": "surprise"
        }
    ]
]


with open('/Users/dsg281/Downloads/EmotionLines/Friends/friends_dev.json') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)
```

am trying to get output in `csv` with columns **"User"**,**"text"**,**"sent"**

Comment: check again, this is incorrect data.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: @RahulNLP this is help you try it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv

Comment: @Harry_pb I have corrected the Json format.Kindly have a look

Comment: @ScottMcC I have corrected the Json format.Kindly have a look

Comment: @RahulNLP - some problem with my solution?

Comment: @jezrael thank you. Its working fine.

Comment: @RahulNLP - Glad can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need (after change json to valid):

`file.json`

```
[
  [
    {
      "user": "Phoebe",
      "text": "Oh my God, hes lost it. Hes totally lost it.",
      "sent": "non-neutral"
    },
    {
      "user": "Monica",
      "text": "What?",
      "sent": "surprise"
    }

   ],
   [{
      "user": "Joey",
      "text": "Hey Estelle, listen",
      "sent": "neutral"
    },
    {
      "user": "Estelle",
      "text": "Well! Well! Well! Joey Tribbiani! So you came back huh? They",
      "sent": "surprise"
    }
  ]     
]
```

---

```
import json

with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in data], ignore_index=False)
print (df)
          sent                                               text     user
0  non-neutral       Oh my God, hes lost it. Hes totally lost it.   Phoebe
1     surprise                                              What?   Monica
0      neutral                                Hey Estelle, listen     Joey
1     surprise  Well! Well! Well! Joey Tribbiani! So you came ...  Estelle
```

And then:

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

EDIT:

If want use non pandas pure python solution, is possible a bit modified with one for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1872081/2901002):

```
import json, csv

with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w+"))
f.writerow(["user", "sent", "text"])

for y in data:
    for x in y: #added for read nested lists
        f.writerow([x["user"], x["sent"], x["text"]])
```

Answer (score 2):

We can concat the lists together with `sum` if we provide a starting value of an empty list `[]`

```
pd.DataFrame(sum(json.load(open('file.json')), [])).to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

sent,text,user
non-neutral,"Oh my God, hes lost it. Hes totally lost it.",Phoebe
surprise,What?,Monica
neutral,"Hey Estelle, listen",Joey
surprise,Well! Well! Well! Joey Tribbiani! So you came back huh? They,Estelle
```