# convert JSON data to CSV format

Tags: python, json, shell, csv

is there any easy way of converting below JSON format to CSV

**JSON**

```
{
"item1" : {
  "status":"Shipped",
  "Location":"TX",
  "trackingno":"z123345df234"
  },
"item2" : {
  "status":"OrderReceived",
  "Location":"AZ",
  "trackingno":"D234235dfawe98"
  }
}
```

**Expected CSV**

```
item1|Shipped|TX|z123345df234
item2|OrderReceived|AZ|D234235dfawe98
```

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv) Possible Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the dictionary to a pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([y[1] for y in u.items()], index = list(u.keys()))
```

So that if I print `df`, I get:

```
df

       Location status          trackingno
item1   TX      Shipped         z123345df234
item2   AZ      OrderReceived   D234235dfawe98
```

Then I would write the results to a `csv` as follows:

```
df.to_csv('NameOfMyDataFrame.csv', index = True)
```

I have put the `index = True` argument to ensure that you see the indices which are the items `['item1', 'item2']`.

Comment: i was using item1 , item2 as examples in actual scenario they are different field names which are not related  like below, so think we can't use a array 

` code `
{
"iphoneX" : {
  "status":"Shipped",
  "Location":"TX",
  "trackingno":"z123345df234"
  },


"Galaxy9" : {
  "status":"OrderReceived",
  "Location":"AZ",
  "trackingno":"D234235dfawe98"
  }
}

Comment: I think this piece of code is very much general.