# Having a set of json and that needs to be converted to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

`{"i": "56", "m1": "IT", "m2": "Area", "r": "faced this problem"}`

`{"i": "57", "m1": "IT", "m2": "Area", "r": "faced this problem3"}`

this is the format of JSON?

Comment: Show what you have tried so its easy to solve your problem you should try 1.read json and loop on json and save data to csv file using csv.write()

Comment: go through this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  .TO CHECK JSON VALIDATOR go through this [Json validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Please read through the answers here: [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1871524/9423231) Write some code yourself and if your code doesn't work post the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
import json

with open('input.json', "r") as in_file:
    data = json.load(in_file)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    for entry in data:
        out_file.write(','.join(entry.values()) + '\n')
```

input.json

```
[
  {
    "i": "56",
    "m1": "IT",
    "m2": "Area",
    "r": "faced this problem"
  },
  {
    "i": "57",
    "m1": "IT",
    "m2": "Area",
    "r": "faced this problem3"
  }
]
```

output.csv

```
56,IT,Area,faced this problem
57,IT,Area,faced this problem3
```

Comment: These data is in json file, same way having lot of data. My code only writing one line and giving encoding error.

Comment: Please explain. Be as detailed as you can.

Comment: Have a json file the format of the file  {"i": "56", "m1": "IT", "m2": "Area", "r": "faced this problem"} , this is one line. Like wise many lines are there in that file. This data needs to transferred to csv file. Using python 3.x

Comment: Do you know how to load JSON file into memory as a python dict? If you dont know - a quick search in the web should help. Once you are done with the JSON loading part you will have the 'DATA' (see my code) and you can go on.

Comment: import json

with open('inputfilePath', "r") as data_file:

    for line in data_file.readlines():
        data = json.loads(line)
        print(data)

data_file.close()

with open('outputfile', 'w') as f:
    for entry in data:
        f.write(','.join(entry.values()) + '\n')

Comment: see above code , I am doing that but getting error as ,   f.write(','.join(entry.values()) + '\n')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Add the code above to the question body (as code) under the title "This is how I load the JSON into dict". Are you able to do it? Do toy get the dict?

Comment: Share the input file as well (or a subset of it)

Comment: Instead of reading from fixed value I am reading it from a input file and the input file format is a dict format. one line is one json in that input json file.

Comment: Share the input file please. (Code was modified with detailed example)

Comment: Input file name : TestInput.json                                                                                                   {"i": "56", "m1": "IT", "m3": "Area", "r": "faced this problem13"}
{"i": "57", "m1": "IT", "m5": "Area", "r": "faced this problem33"}
{"i": "58", "m1": "IT", "m28": "Area", "r": "faced this problem55"}
{"i": "60", "m1": "IT", "m26: "Area", "r": "faced this problem3"}

Comment: Add square brackets around the data: [ {"i": "56", "m1": "IT", "m3": "Area", "r": "faced this problem13"} {"i": "57", "m1": "IT", "m5": "Area", "r": "faced this problem33"} {"i": "58", "m1": "IT", "m28": "Area", "r": "faced this problem55"} {"i": "60", "m1": "IT", "m26: "Area", "r": "faced this problem3"} ] in the file. **See the example above**

Comment: after adding that  getting this error :    data = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 1 (char 1405)

Comment: Use https://pastebin.com/ and share a **formatted** and **valid** sample JSON. Use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ in order to check that your JSON is valid