# How to convert a text file with JSON values to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a text file which contains `json` in each row.

**Sample Data:** in `file.text`

```
{"id": "testid1","title": "testtitle1","link": "testlink1","description": "testdes2","entities": ["en1", "en2"]}
{"id": "testid2","title": "testtitle2","link": "testlink2","description": "testdes2","entities": [""]}
{"id": "testid1","title": "testtitle1","link": "testlink1","description": "testdesc","entities": ["en1", "en2", "en3"]}
```

**Output required:**

```
id  title   link    description entities__001   entities__002   entities__003
testid1 testtitle1  testlink1   testdes2    en1 en2 
testid2 testtitle2  testlink2   testdes2            
testid1 testtitle1  testlink1   testdesc    en1 en2 en3
```

Please suggest, how can I do the same in python?

I have tried to convert my file to `csv` online using https://json-csv.com/. However, It only supports up to 1 MB file in free account and my file size is around 200 MB. However, using this link I was able to covert it successfully with desired output.

Comment: Please show the code _you_ wrote to do this and describe the issues you're experiencing with it, if any.

Comment: maybe this question is what you need: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the file and process the data (convert from string to json)

```
import json
with open(r".\data_file.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
processed_data = [json.loads(line) for line in data]
```

then iterate over the documents to add new fields (to flatten the data). There are more efficient ways but this works.

```
import pandas as pd
for document in processed_data:
    for i in range(len(document["entities"])):
        document["entities_{}".format(i+1)] = document["entities"][i]
df = pd.DataFrame(processed_data)
#remove original column (if needed)
del df["entities"]
```

then just save as csv

```
df.to_csv(r"./out_folder/out_data.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly according to my requirement. +1