# Writing JSON data into CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a dynamic json, in whcih key(attributes) will be different based on records.

I want to write below json data into csv file:

```
[{"Id": "12345",
  "attributes": {"Address": [{"label": "United Kingdom",
                              "value": {"AddressLine": [{"value": "Baker "
                                                                  "Street"}]}},
                             {"label": "United States",
                              "value": {"AddressLine": [{"value": "Florida"}]}}],
                 "CountryCode": [{"value": "Australia"}],
                 "Identifiers": [{"value": {"Type": [{"value": "Licence Id"}]}},
                                 {"value": {"Type": [{"value": "NPI"}]}}],
                 "StatusReasonCode": [{"value": "XXX"}],
                 "UniqueId": [{"value": "71581742"}]},
  "createdBy": "Rahul"}]
```

Data is expected in below format of the csv:

```
ID, createdBy, CountryCode, StatusReasonCode, Identifiers, UniqueId, AddressLine
12345,Rahul,Australia,XXX,Licence Id,71581742,Baker Street
12345,Rahul,Australia,XXX,NPI,71581742,Florida
```

Here is my code to extract the data from json:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for key,value in data.items():

    if(type(value))==str:
        print(key + ',' + value)
    # global res
    res =[]
    if(type(value))==list:
        for fg in value:
            crosswalk_final=fg['value']
    if (type(value))== dict:
        for key1,val in value.items():
            for k in val:
                if type(k['value']) == dict:

                   for sub_key,sub_value in k.items():

                      if(type(sub_value)) == dict:
                          for child_key,child_value in sub_value.items():

                              if(type(child_value)) == list:
                                for m in child_value:

                                    if type(m['value']) == dict:
                                        for qaq,waq in m.items():

                                            if (isinstance(waq, dict)):
                                                for our,pur in waq.items():

                                                    for qq in pur:
                                                       print(our+','+qq['value'])

                                    else:
                                        pass
                                        print(key1+'_'+sub_key+'_'+child_key+','+m['value'])

                else:
                    attr1=(key+'_'+key1+','+k['value'])
                    print((attr1))
```

The above code is giving me result in below format:

```
Id,12345
createdBy,Rahul
attributes_UniqueId,71581742
attributes_CountryCode,Australia
attributes_StatusReasonCode,XXX
Address_value_AddressLine,Baker Street
Address_value_AddressLine,Florida
Identifiers_value_Type,Licence Id
Identifiers_value_Type,NPI
```

However I am not sure how to write it in my csv (in the same format shown above).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: My challenge here is to make a new row in the CSV file , if there are more than one values of any of the attribute(key) in josn record

Answer (score -1):

Write a function that flattens the dictionary into a list with constant length. If key is missing, set value to None.
Example:

```
data_dict = {"a": 1, "c": 12, "b": 0}
data_list = [data_dict.get("a"), data_dict.get("b"), data_dict.get("c")]
```

Then insert in csv.