# How to process ldap3 entries to json or list for further data processing?

Tags: python, dictionary, ldap3

I need to get data from a server using LDAP. I'm using ldap3 and am getting all the attributes and responses that I need however, their stuck in the ldap.abstract.entry.entry class. I tried severall methods to get the data into a json or list form but it never worked the way I expected it to work.

For example I tried:

```py
entry = conn.entries
current_data = (entry.entry_to_json())
print(type(current_data))
print(len(current_data))
>>> <class 'str'>
>>> 480
```

That however, caused all my data to be a single string of length 480 or more. I tried working with this but that just proved to be very difficult. So I tried the following to convert the string to a dict:

```py
current_data = (entry[0].entry_to_json())
current_data = ast.literal_eval(current_data)
print(type(current_data))
print(len(current_data))
>>> <class 'dict'>
>>> 2
```

However, now I can't access all the different attributes seperately. My goal is to write all of the data that I get from the LDAP Query to a CSV so that other applications can work with it. But currently I'm stuck as I can't get the data into a JSON or CSV format.

How can I get and process the data from the `conn.entries` so that I can write each attribute to a seperate column in a CSV?

Best wishes,

C. Zerbe

Edit:

This is a sample of what I get when I use `(entry.entry_to_json())`:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "dcxLDOUniqueCN": [
            "XXXX"
        ],
        "dcxPostalAddress": [
            "XXX"
        ],
        "dcxSupervisor": [
            "XXX"
        ],
        "mail": [
            "XXX"
        ],
        "mobile": [],
        "uid": [
            "XXX"
        ]
    },
    "dn": "XXX"
}
{
    "attributes": {
        "dcxLDOUniqueCN": [],
        "dcxPostalAddress": [
            "XXX"
        ],
        "dcxSupervisor": [
            "XXX"
        ],
        "mail": [],
        "mobile": [],
        "uid": [
            "XXX"
        ]
    },
    "dn": "XXX"
}
```

Comment: What would a sample of the data look like in `json` form? There are numerous questions transforming [json to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: The Problem I'm having is that the comand `current_data = (entry.entry_to_json())` doesn't actually give me a json class variable but instead gives me a string.

Comment: Right, and you are moving in the correct direction using `ast.literal_eval`. Once you have a functioning dictionary (there isn't really a json class object in python), there are ways to convert a dictionary to a csv. Can you add a sample of what your json looks like in the question? You can substitute potentially sensitive info (I'm guessing LDAP info may or may not have that) with dummy entries

Answer (score 7):

I know it's late, but in case that someone else is looking for this...

From https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html#entries

> Attributes are stored in an internal dictionary with case insensitive access. You can even access the raw attribute with the entry_raw_attribute(attribute_name) to get an attribute raw value, or property entry_raw_attributes to get the whole raw attributes dictionary.

So `entry.entry_raw_attributes` will give you the dictionary you want.

Comment: Just playing around with the ldap and ldap3 modules. I am exporting to LDIF, so that I'm fine but I was just curious. THX

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do something similar as I was working with the `ldap3` library and returning responses in JSON form from a `Flask` API. I found this entry in my own search, so hopefully this may help others.

As you've already discovered, the `entry_to_json()` method converts the details in the [`ldap3.abstract.entry.Entry`](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/abstraction.html#entry) object to a JSON string. This can be combined with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) built-in library to be converted into a Python dictionary using `json.loads()`.

Using your example in IDLE, but skipping the `ldap3` components for brevity:

```
>>> my_entry = '''{
"attributes": {
    "dcxLDOUniqueCN": [
        "XXXX"
    ],
    "dcxPostalAddress": [
        "XXX"
    ],
    "dcxSupervisor": [
        "XXX"
    ],
    "mail": [
        "XXX"
    ],
    "mobile": [],
    "uid": [
        "XXX"
    ]
},
"dn": "XXX"
}'''
>>> print(type(my_entry))
<class 'str'>    
>>> import json
>>> my_entry_dict = json.loads(my_entry)
>>> print(type(my_entry_dict))
<class 'dict'>
print(my_entry_dict)
{'attributes': {'dcxLDOUniqueCN': ['XXXX'], 'dcxPostalAddress': ['XXX'], 'dcxSupervisor': ['XXX'], 'mail': ['XXX'], 'mobile': [], 'uid': ['XXX']}, 'dn': 'XXX'}
```