# Converting nested JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

This question has been probably asked several times here. I've been trying to make my nested JSON file flat and convert it to CSV, however the closest I could get was to list field names: `MyCount, from, Mysize, Allhits, aggs`, but with no values:

Output.csv:

```
""
Mycount
from
Mysize
Allhits
aggs
```

I've been trying this code to convert JSON to CSV:

```
import json
import csv

def get_leaves(item, key=None):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item.keys():
            leaves.update(get_leaves(item[i], i))
        return leaves
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item:
            leaves.update(get_leaves(i, key))
        return leaves
    else:
        return {key : item}


with open('path/to/my/file.json') as f_input:
    json_data = json.load(f_input)

# Paresing all entries to get the complete fieldname list
fieldnames = set()

for entry in json_data:
    fieldnames.update(get_leaves(entry).keys())

with open('/path/to/myoutput.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(fieldnames))
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(get_leaves(entry) for entry in json_data)
```

The JSON structure is like this:

```
{"Mycount":538,
"from":0,
"Mysize":1000,
"Allhits":[{
    "isVerified":true,
    "backgroundColor":"FF720B",
    "name":"yourShop",
    "Id":"12345678",
    "ActionItems":[{
        "subtitle":"Click here to start",
        "body":null,
        "language":"de",
        "title":"Start here",
        "isDefault":true}],
        "tintColor":"FFFFFF",
        "shoppingHours":[{"hours":[{"day":["SUNDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["MONDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["SATURDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["FRIDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["THURSDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["WEDNESDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["TUESDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]}]}],
        "LogoUrl":"https://url/to/my/logo.png",
        "coverage":[{
            "country":"*",
            "language":"*",
            "ratio":1}],
        "shoppingHours2":[{"hours":[{"day":["SUNDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["MONDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["SATURDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["FRIDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["THURSDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["WEDNESDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]},{"day":["TUESDAY"],"timeRange":[{"allDay":false,"from":25200,"to":68400}]}]}],
        "group":"shop_open",
        "timeZone":"CET",
        "phone":"+1234567890",
        "modTime":1234567890,
        "intId":"+123456789",
        "Logo2Url":"https://link/to/my/logo.png"}],
"aggs":{}}
```

Would this be easy to accomplish using pandas module? I'm still learning python so I would appreciate any guidance with this. The minimum what I need from this json file is to extract  `id, intId, name, ratio` and values for this field names into CSV.

The desired output should be (alternatively it could have all field names and values and I would then be able to extract the fields I need from CSV directly):

```
id          intId         name    ratio
12345678    123456789   yourShop    1
```

This is just version for one record, but my output file has to include rows for all IDs present in JSON file.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT**
I've tried also the following:

```
import json
import csv


x = '/path/to/myrecords.json'

x = json.loads(x)

f.writerow(["name", "id", "intId", "ratio"])

f = csv.writer(open("/path/to/my/output.csv", "w", newline=''))

for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["Allhits"]["name"],
                x["Allhits"]["id"],
                x["Allhits"]["ActionItems"]["intId"],
                x["Allhits"]["ActionItems"]["ratio"]])
```

but received this error for `x = json.loads(x)` step:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Why to not just retrieve all required values using keys into a list and write to csv file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: @F.NiX I've tried but still struggling (see EDIT paragraph at the bottom of my post). Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: @Olvin, would you be able to share some code? This would help a lot considering that I'm just a beginner with Python! Thanks!

Comment: @Baobab1988, you're doing `for x in x`. First of all, it won't work, but even if it will, your example contains single json object, not an array. What are you trying to iterate over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will loop through the `Allhits` list and get the minimum set of data you need:

```
import json
import csv

with open('/path/to/myrecords.json') as f_input:
    json_data = json.load(f_input)

with open('/path/to/my/output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output  = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["id", "intId", "name", "ratio"])
    for x in json_data['Allhits']:
        csv_output.writerow([x["Id"], x["intId"], x["name"], x["coverage"][0]["ratio"]])
```

Comment: @Baobab1988 Good to hear that. You were nearly there.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to flatten whole json, including arrays, you could do something like this with recurtion:

```py
import json
import csv

def flatten(item, prefix=None):
    result = {}
    if isinstance(item, list):
        item = { i : item[i] for i in range(0, len(item) )}
    for key, val in item.items():
        prefixed_key = f"{prefix}{key}" if prefix else str(key)
        if isinstance(val, list) or isinstance(val, dict):
            result = {**result, **flatten(val, f"{prefixed_key}_")}
        else:
            result[prefixed_key] = val

    return result


with open('test.json') as f_input, open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    hits = json.load(f_input)["Allhits"]
    header_written = False
    for hit in hits:
        flat = flatten(hit)
        if not header_written:
            writer.writerow(flat.keys())
            header_written = True
        writer.writerow(flat.values())
```

with this you'd get this csv monstrocity:

```
isVerified,backgroundColor,name,Id,ActionItems_0_subtitle,ActionItems_0_body,ActionItems_0_language,ActionItems_0_title,ActionItems_0_isDefault,tintColor,shoppingHours_0_hours_0_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_0_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_0_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_0_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours_0_hours_1_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_1_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_1_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_1_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours_0_hours_2_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_2_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_2_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_2_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours_0_hours_3_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_3_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_3_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_3_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours_0_hours_4_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_4_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_4_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_4_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours_0_hours_5_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_5_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_5_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_5_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours_0_hours_6_day_0,shoppingHours_0_hours_6_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours_0_hours_6_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours_0_hours_6_timeRange_0_to,LogoUrl,coverage_0_country,coverage_0_language,coverage_0_ratio,shoppingHours2_0_hours_0_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_0_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_0_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_0_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours2_0_hours_1_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_1_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_1_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_1_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours2_0_hours_2_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_2_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_2_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_2_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours2_0_hours_3_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_3_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_3_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_3_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours2_0_hours_4_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_4_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_4_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_4_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours2_0_hours_5_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_5_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_5_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_5_timeRange_0_to,shoppingHours2_0_hours_6_day_0,shoppingHours2_0_hours_6_timeRange_0_allDay,shoppingHours2_0_hours_6_timeRange_0_from,shoppingHours2_0_hours_6_timeRange_0_to,group,timeZone,phone,modTime,intId,Logo2Url
True,FF720B,yourShop,12345678,Click here to start,,de,Start here,True,FFFFFF,SUNDAY,False,25200,68400,MONDAY,False,25200,68400,SATURDAY,False,25200,68400,FRIDAY,False,25200,68400,THURSDAY,False,25200,68400,WEDNESDAY,False,25200,68400,TUESDAY,False,25200,68400,https://url/to/my/logo.png,*,*,1,SUNDAY,False,25200,68400,MONDAY,False,25200,68400,SATURDAY,False,25200,68400,FRIDAY,False,25200,68400,THURSDAY,False,25200,68400,WEDNESDAY,False,25200,68400,TUESDAY,False,25200,68400,shop_open,CET,+1234567890,1234567890,+123456789,https://link/to/my/logo.png
```

But if you only need specific keys, you can just iterate through your `Allhits` and retrieve whats needed like this:

```
with open('test.json') as f_input, open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    writer = csv.writer(f_output)
    hits = json.load(f_input)["Allhits"]
    writer.writerow(["Id", "intId", "name", "ratio"])
    for hit in hits:
        writer.writerow([hit["Id"], hit["intId"], hit["name"], hit["coverage"][0]["ratio"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = json.loads(x)
```

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

This is because `json.loads` expects a string containing the json data while the file name is passed as x.

As `"Allhits":[{...}]` is a single element list containing a dictionary 
replace  `x["Allhits"]["name"]` with `x["Allhits"][0]["name"]`. Similarly when accessing the other elements like `"Id"`.