# Parse JSON array into csv file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response in the form of a JSON object from a request in the pattern:

`{"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[I,II,III,IV,V],"c":[p,q,r,s,t]}`

How can I parse this `json` object into a csv file in `python` containing `a,b,c` as column names and the values as data in rows as:

```
a    b      c
1    I      p
2    II     q
3    III    r
4    IV     s
5    V      t
```

Code for json response:

```
url="some url"

page=requests.get(url)
output = page.json()
```

The closest answer I got to was in [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

I have tried to convert it into a pandas `dataframe` and iterate through it
but I can't get the work around with it with my JSON object.

Comment: How about to provide your code using `pandas`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is an answer in the link you provide which creates a `csv` file. Did you try that? Did you have to make any changes to get it to work for your data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pip3 install pandas
```

Install the Pandas library with the above command.

```
import pandas as pd

output = {
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "b": ["I", "II", "III", "IV", "V"],
    "c": ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(output)
df.to_csv("filename.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mohammadreza .The ** index=False, encoding="utf-8" ** part did the trick for me.