# How to convert JSON to a CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

Whats the best way to convert the below JSON to CSV in python?

```
[{
    "header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r",
    "data": "1_qweqwe|sometitle|320|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle2|130|0|0|0|0",
    "totalCount": 13
},
{
    "header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r",
    "data": "1_abccd|sometitle3|360|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle4|320|0|0|0|0",
    "totalCount": 23
},
{
    "header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r",
    "data": "1_sdsfsd|sometitle5|600|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle6|100|0|0|0|0",
    "totalCount": 33
}]
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html as reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: Need more clarification. Does `data` holds values for all columns? Is `header` fixed for all items and is the expected header of the CSV file?  What `totalCount` means? Is it another column value?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best i could do:

```
import csv
import json

a=[]
x = """[{"header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r","data": "1_qweqwe|sometitle|320|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle2|130|0|0|0|0","totalCount": 13},{"header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r","data": "1_abccd|sometitle3|360|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle4|320|0|0|0|0","totalCount": 23},{"header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r","data": "1_sdsfsd|sometitle5|600|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle6|100|0|0|0|0","totalCount": 33}]"""

x = json.loads(x)

f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))

f.writerow(["_id", "_n", "_p", "_e", "_v", "_d", "_r","_tt"])

for x in x:
    temp=x["totalCount"]
    for x in x["data"].split(";"):
        print(x)
        f.writerow([x.split('|')[0],x.split('|')[1],x.split('|')[2],x.split('|')[3],x.split('|')[4],x.split('|')[5],x.split('|')[6],temp])
    f.writerow([])
```

Let me know if we could improve it further.

Comment: This question is closed now. So could not post any answer. You can try copying the below code. However, I am not sure if the formatting will be preserved.

Comment: import numpy

json_obj = [{
    "header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r",
    "data": "1_qweqwe|sometitle|320|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle2|130|0|0|0|0",
    "totalCount": 13
},
{
    "header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r",
    "data": "1_abccd|sometitle3|360|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle4|320|0|0|0|0",
    "totalCount": 23
},
{
    "header": "_id|_n|_p|_e|_v|_d|_r",
    "data": "1_sdsfsd|sometitle5|600|0|0|0|0;1_asdasdasd|sometitle6|100|0|0|0|0",
    "totalCount": 33
}]

header = ["_id", "_n", "_p", "_e", "_v", "_d", "_r","_tt"]
print(header)

Comment: table = [header]  # initialise table with the header
for item in json_obj:
    data = item["data"].split(";")  # get individual row data from json
    for row_data_text in data:
        row_data = row_data_text.split("|")
        row_data.append(item["totalCount"])
        table.append(row_data)  # add the row data to the table


print(table)
np_table = numpy.asarray(table)
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", np_table, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")