# How to convert this JSON structure into a csv?

Tags: python, json, pandas

The data is not real for privacy purposes.
My goal is to convert this structure to a csv.
The following columns are: {"city", "line/Address", "postalCode","state", "birthDate","Boolean", "url", "code", "display", "system"}
I think that I need to make this into a dictionary.

```
{
  "address": [
    {
      "city": "Sam town",
      "line": [
        "PO BOX 454545415198"
      ],
      "postalCode": "99999999",
      "state": "999"
    }
  ],
  "birthDate": "2040-15-84",
  "Boolean": false,
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "none",
      "valueCoding": {
        "code": "99999",
        "display": "None",
        "system": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables/race"
      }
    }
```

Comment: So, what have you tried? Please, check [ask].

Comment: Does this post answer your question? [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1871524/3281097)

Comment: your data is giving me syntax error

Comment: @enke He didn't close the bracket for the extension value

Answer (score 0):

With the pandas [library](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/index.html), this is as easy as using two commands!

```
df = pd.read_json()
```

read_json converts a JSON string to a pandas object (either a series or dataframe). Then:

```
df.to_csv()
```

Which can either return a string or write directly to a csv-file. See the docs for [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd

with open('jsonfile.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
    df = pd.read_json(inputfile)

df.to_csv('csvfile.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: So I am pulling this data form an API so it comes in as just that format. It has to be converted into Json format then I need to convert into pandas df.