# Python: I need to convert this json file to csv in a structured format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

Question - I need to convert this json file to csv or excel (xlsx, xls), these all three formats are acceptable.

Input [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m83i9NgtC1lDsuPp_Mlgk-GBz02K1PI_/view)

Sample:

> {"textAnnotations": [{"locale": "en", "description": "KAISER
> BROTHERS\nWorld\nFood\nSINCE MARTX\n14:25 BEECHNUT STREET\nHouston, TX
> 77083\n281 988 4566\nTRY OUR CHARGA TODAY!!!\nReceipt
> #:\n032203\nStore:\nR$1\nTerminal:\n05\nFRE BITTERMELON 1.85 E\nINDIAN LB\n0.930 lb @ $1.99/lb\nBEANS FAVA LB\n2.03 E\n1.020 lb @
> $1.99/lb\nFRE TOMATILLO GREEN 0.85 E\nLB\n0.570 lb @ $1.49/lb\nCHILLI
> LONG LB 2.02 E\n0.580 lb @ $3.49/lb\n5.99 T\nGOD NUPUR HENNA\nMEHENDI
> 400G\nFRE PURSLANE /KULFA\n1.49 E\nEA\nBABY TARO ARVI LB\n1.16
> E\n0.780 lb @ $1.49/lb\nFRE LEMON EA\n0.99 E\n3 @ 0.33\nGINGER ROOT
> LB\n1.21 E\n0.610 lb @ $1.99/lb\nFRE ONION YELLOW LB\n1.96 E\n3.990 lb
> @ $0.49/lb\nFRE CABBAGE GREEN\n1.21 E\nLB\n3.680 lb @ $0.33/lb\n2.49
> E\n2.49 E\n2.49 E\n2.55 E\n5.99 E\n4.99 E\n1.99 T\n1.99 T\n4.54
> E\n6.40 E\n56.68\n0.82\n57.50\n57.50\n57.50\n0.00\n5/12/22 8:36
> PM\nClark: HABIB\nMember Name: CHANELLER DEV\nMember ID:
> 7135578001\n4030\n4239\n3352\n4536\n8901023022548\n3170\n4018\n4109\n4077\n4152\n4069\n051179421158
> SWAD ROSE WATER\n440ML\n051179421158 SWAD ROSE
> WATER\n440ML\n051179421158 SWAD ROSE WATER\n440ML\n4248\nFRE TOMATO
> ROMA LB\n2.860 lb @ $0.89/lb\n796252300271 YOGURT DRINK MINT\n1/2
> GAL\n796252700408 MALAI CREAM 8 OZ\nBREAKFAST\n8954000114797 HEM
> SAFFRON OIL\n30ML\n8964000114306 HEM CARROT OIL 30ML\n00535\nPPACK CK
> LEG QRT\nSKINLESS\n3,047 @ 1.49\n00530\nPPACK CK THIGH\nGROUND
> (KEEMA)\n2.14 @ 2.99\nSUBTOTAL\nSALES TAX\nTOTAL\nCredit\nTOTAL
> TENDERED\nChange\nCARD INFORMATION:\nXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXX\nName:\nCard
> Type:\nAccount:\nAmount:\nApproval #:\nDate:\nReference
> #:\nMID:\nMode:\nCard Name: VISA CREDIT\nAID:\nA00000000XXXXX\nVisa\nXXXX\nUSD
> $57.50\n86018D\n5/12/22\n001032203001\n**1620\nIssuer\nToday you saved
> $1.35\nThank you for shopping with us!\nFINAL SALE, FINAL SALE, FINAL
> SALE\nNo return or exc

I had get this file from google vison API,

Expecting [output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xOEgJluHojHApnDZPEm7juumcF6FRwjv-Ne-ENIyhf0/edit?usp=sharing) file. In particularly, table2 data was expected data.

both output formats are acceptable

sample output data format 1

| left | center | right | right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4030 | FRE BITTERMELON INDIAN LB 0.930 1b 0 | $1.99/lb | 1.85 E |
| 4239 | BEANS FAVA LB 1.020 1b 0 | $1.99/lb | 2.03 E |

sample output data format 2

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4030 | FRE BITTERMELON INDIAN LB 0.930 1b 0 $1.99/lb | 1.85 E |
| 4239 | BEANS FAVA LB 1.020 1b 0 $1.99/lb | 2.03 E |

sample output image format 2

[image: detailed output please check above mentioned link]

I was try these two types of library's, but output was not getting in a expected format, anyone can help me here.

references - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71133089/how-to-convert-this-json-structure-into-a-csv)

```
import json
import pandas as pd
# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json')
  
# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)
  
# Iterating through the json
# list
a = data['textAnnotations'][0]['description']
data = {'A': a}
#data = {'A': a[0:]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([data])
```

output [image: getting data in a single cell]

Another method i was try

```
import pandas as pd
# As of Pandas 1.01, json_normalize as pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated and is now exposed in the top-level namespace.
# from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pathlib import Path
import json

# set path to file
p = Path(r'data.json')

# read json
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# create dataframe
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# save to csv
#df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

output [image: getting data in a single row]

Comment: can you provide a sample of the file (without having to leave SO)

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m83i9NgtC1lDsuPp_Mlgk-GBz02K1PI_/view) 

this is a sample file. thank you for your support.

sorry, not getting you point, from this sentence (without having to leave SO)

Comment: basically a user who wants to answer a question should not have to leave stackoverflow to help, provide the file as text in your question

Comment: sorry, Unable to add input file due to character exceeded warning was shown by stack overflow.

Comment: don't add the whole file. a few sample *text* lines (not images) is fine.