# How to export JavaScript object to Google Sheet using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have a JavaScript object like this

```
[{ a: "123", b: "456" }, { a: "321", b: "654" }]
```

Is there any way to export it to Google Sheet like this using NodeJs

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the values of `[{ a: "123", b: "456" }, { a: "321", b: "654" }]` to the Spreadsheet using Node.js.

In this case, how about using [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)?

### Usage:

#### 1. Install google-spreadsheet.

You can see it at [here](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/).

#### 2. Authorization

I thought that in this case, the service account might be useful.

You can see the method for authorization at [here](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/getting-started/authentication).

#### 3. Sample script:

```js
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");

const creds = require("credential.json"); // Please set your credential file.

const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("##"); // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

const sample = async () => {
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
  await doc.loadInfo();
  const worksheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // Here, 1st tab on Google Spreadsheet is used.

  // This is from your sample value.
  const values = [
    { a: "123", b: "456" },
    { a: "321", b: "654" },
  ];
  await worksheet.setHeaderRow(["a", "b"]); // This is the header row.
  await worksheet.addRows(values); // Your value is put to the sheet.
};

sample();
```

- When this script is run, the result in your sample image is obtained.

### References:

- [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet)
- [document of google-spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/)

Answer (score -1):

You could **convert your JSON content to CSV** and just use the Google Sheets import.

1. Convert your JSON file / data to CSV using a npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv [How can I convert JSON to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv)
2. Create a CSV file with it (you can console.log your content and copy it or just use [fs](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp) to create a file)
3. Import the csv file by using the UI: [image][image]

You could **also use an online tool** for it: https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm
There you just have to copy your json and can even download a "Excel"-file with it. (This file can get imported like CSV as well)

Another way is to use a **Google Sheets plugin**. However I was only able to find tools for loading JSON via an URL / API. E.g.: https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a

Comment: The question is about how to programatically upload the json format data to a google sheet, using nodejs. Not importing and uploading manually.